# Why my browser not able to run updated code?

Tags: javascript

I am changing my javascript code but browser somehow using old code which i deleted, somehow caching old code. Why is it happening suddenly? And how to prevent it?

Comment: Ctrl+F5 should completely refresh the page including cached scripts and CSS.

Comment: press ctrl+f5 to refresh

Comment: @Focki why did it startes suddenly and why refreshing browser stopped working?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it is mainly related to time and actual browser cache storage (may not exceed 12MB or sth like that). I think you can set the cache storage limit in your browser settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ctr+Shift+R for every run.

Comment: @Adyson is also right both works.

Comment: @Adyson But can you guys include explanation why is that? as I was refresing the browser and it started suddenly.

Comment: It's simply overriding the cache. In simple words, when you do that, the browser will ignore the cache and fetch the fresh copy from the server.